# Loopback - one-to-many relation between 3 models

Tags: ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, loopback, apiconnect

I'm using IBM API Connect for a Loopback application. I've 3 models - owner, home and room. The relationship is described as follows:

OWNER:

- an owner might have one or more than one home(s)
- a home or all of the homes belong to a particular owner

HOME:

- a home would have more than one rooms
- all of the rooms belongs to a particular home

In my case, through API Connect CLI, Owner is an REST exposed model (REST resource) and is supposed to be directly related to the Home model via one-to-many relationship. Home & Room are two models which are not exposed to REST. Home is directly related to Room via one-to-many relationship. Owner and Room are not directly related to each other but is related via Home model.

I want to get the HTTP URL in these forms:

```
/owners/{id}/homes/{id}/rooms/{id}
```

to get details of a room for a particular home of the owner

I've chosed one-to-many relationship for Owner-Home and Home-Room with respective foreign key. Since its not a many-to-many relationship, I did not use any through model.

The URLs that I'm getting doesn't have any Room counterpart :

```
/owners/{id}/homes/{id}
```

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Why would you need to guery a room from a owner ID and a home ID if you already have the room ID you are querying for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a function called `nestRemoting()`.

Take your case as an example, you need to call `Owner.nestRemoting('homes')` in the boot file to enable nest endpoints

Details please see our doc: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Nested-queries.html

In loopback-example-relations I created a branch contains your models and relations, and how to get nest remote apis work, please check:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-relations/blob/example/nest-relation/server/boot/initNestRelation.js#L3-L4